# Reading the data from an internet file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to import in a file the data from the following URL:

```
"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XLB&a=0&b=24&c=2016&d=0&e=24&f=2017&g=v&ignore=.csv"
```

It consists of 4 data lines with two data on each line.

I have tried many things, for example:

```
data = requests.get('http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XLB&a=0&b=24&c=2016&d=0&e=24&f=2017&g=v&ignore=.csv')
for line in data:
    print line
    f = open(name_of_file, 'a')
    for i in range(len(data)-1,0,-1):            
        data_to_write = (""+ convert_date(data[0]) + ','
                            + data[1] + ',' 
                            + '\n')
        f.write(data_to_write) 
    f.close()
```

But I always receive answers such as

> object of type response has no len()

or similar answer. It seems that in fact I am always opening a file in the browser (Safari on Mac) but not reading the content of the file?
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you Mike @mike . Your solution works perfectly. Solved.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @mike Accepted. I learned another thing !

Comment: This site is all about learning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will write the data to a file:

```
import requests

name_of_file = 'yahoo.txt'

data = requests.get('http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XLB&a=0&b=24&c=2016&d=0&e=24&f=2017&g=v&ignore=.csv')
with open(name_of_file, 'a') as fobj:
    fobj.write(data.text)
```

File content:

```
Date,Dividends
2016-12-16,0.334000
2016-09-16,0.242000
2016-06-17,0.235000
2016-03-18,0.157000
```